# How to run elasticsearch-hq?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I am trying to run [elasticsearch-hq](https://github.com/royrusso/elasticsearch-HQ) to monitor my ES cluster.

As I understand it is a node.js application. I've tried to run

> npm install

and it seems to be fine.. as far as I understand (that's what most node.js tutorials say to do...)

But when I run

> node app

it returns:

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module '/elasticsearch-HQ/app'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
```

what can I do with that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than run this as a node.js application (particularly if you're not familiar with node.js) why don't you run it as a plugin? That's what we do:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.x/modules-plugins.html

In this case you'll run the following commands:

```
cd <yourelasticsearchhome>/bin
plugin -install royrusso/elasticsearch-HQ
```

Then navigate to `http://<yourhost>:9200/_plugin/HQ/`

And you should be good to go -

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation, you also need to install grunt.
Once that's done try the following again:
*npm install && grunt dist*